# Is there any way to run a Jenkins job on Zephyr Squad for Jira test-case execution status change?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-zephyr

So i have a private Jira Server 8.5.7 with Zephyr Squad (9.1.3) plugin for it.

What this plugin does is adds a custom fields with Test Steps and Test Execution Status to the Jira Issue.
Test Steps

[image: 1]

Test Execution Status

[image: 2]

What i need to do is to make Jira send an API request to remote Jenkins server once Test Execution Status has changed(by the QA Engineer).

The problem is that these custom fields are not CustomFields in Jira-terms - they are not shown on a Custom Fields page for the project. It does not appear on Workflows(because its not part of Issue flow, rather inside one), so i cant use webhooks. I cannot add a Custom Event for them changing. I also cannot add a Custom Listener for that Execution status change, because there's nothing to connect to - when i change the Execution Status the IssueUpdate event does not fire. No event is fired at all.
It just sends a request to Zephyr's own plugin API (/rest/zephyr/)

I dont know if it was made intentionally or just with flaws or am i stupid.

Is there any way to make Jira send API requests one that execution status change? Maybe there is Listener class specific for that execution status i dont know about? Or maybe one could write a custom plugin to attach to that status change somehow?

The Jira and Zephyr versions are highest i could get.

I know i can make it work with Jira Issue status change, but that would be my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else got stuck with this.

I never found a way to do it with Zephyr Squad. However, there is a similar thing called Zephyr Scale.
Basically, does all the same things, has a slighty different UI, but most importantly - triggers an event when test execution status changed, which could be set on listener.

Comment: from here you may add scripts [like this](https://library.adaptavist.com/entity/transition-issue-testexecution-change)